# Spamassassin don't check my mails

Tags: debian, postfix, spamassassin

I've a problem on my debian 10 server. Spamassassin don't inspect my mail (I've check the headers and send mail spam tests from other domaisn) . The spamassassin daemon is running but something is wrong in my postfix configuration (I only use 587 STARTTLS on my clients). 
My spamd.log

```
[root@server ~]# cat /var/log/spamassassin/spamd.log
Sun Jun  7 00:25:28 2020 [24193] info: logger: removing stderr method
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: zoom: able to use 390/391 'body_0' compiled rules (99.744%)
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783 (running version 3.4.2)
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: spamd: server pid: 24197
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 24200
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 24201
Sun Jun  7 00:25:30 2020 [24197] info: prefork: child states: II
```

My running process:

```
ps -aux | grep spamd
root     25108  1.9  4.7 111104 95196 ?        Ss   00:49   0:02 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --username spamd --helper-home-dir ${SAHOME} -s /var/log/spamd.log
spamd    25109  0.2  4.8 113784 97448 ?        S    00:49   0:00 spamd child
spamd    25110  0.0  4.5 111388 90984 ?        S    00:49   0:00 spamd child
postfix  25119  0.0  0.3  47584  6988 ?        S    00:50   0:00 pipe -n spamassassin -t unix flags=R user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
root     25144  0.0  0.0   8116   880 pts/0    S+   00:51   0:00 grep spamd
```

And here is my /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd 
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
spamassassin unix  -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

What do I have wrong?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Incoming mail uses the SMTP port `25/tcp`. In the `master.cf` this line represents the smtpd instance serving this purpose:

```
smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
```

As it doesn't have any setting overridden with `-o`, it uses the settings from `main.cf`. From [`master(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html):

> `-o { name = value }` (long form, Postfix >= 3.0)
>  `-o name=value`
>   (short form)
>
> Override the named [main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) configuration parameter. The parameter
>   value can refer to other parameters as `$name` etc., just like in
>   [main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

You haven't disclosed your `main.cf`, but this suggests you have added Spamassassin (probably only) to the smtpd instance listening on smtps port `465/tcp`:

```
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
   ...
   -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

Just like the *submission* on port `587/tcp`, this is for mail from your clients, not for mail from other MTAs. The only difference is that the connection is wrapped inside TLS instead of switching to encrypted communication with the `STARTTLS` command.